# Can functions behave differently depending on the expressions they are placed in?

Tags: functions, terminology

Let us define f(x) as the following:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x)  & \text{if f(x) is being floored ($\lfloor x \rfloor$)} \\ h(x) & \text{if multiplication by anything other than 1 is being applied to f(x)} \\ j(x) & \text {otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Such a function changes its behavior depending on what operation is applied to it. So now for some questions:

1. Is such an function valid or would it be nonsense as I fear?
2. Have they been used or studied, if so, where?
3. Assuming it does exist and is valid, what sort of algebraic rules surround it?

Comment: "if multiplication is being applied to f" what does this mean?

Comment: I think OP means if you do something like $y(x)+f(x)$, then this is actually $y(x)+g(x)$ however $y(x)\cdot f(x) := y(x)\cdot h(x)$.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck but $c*f(x)=f(x)+....+f(x)$ $c$ times

Comment: Just a note:  the distributive property couldn't hold in this function space since we can find functions $K$ and $L$ as well as functions $g, h$ such that  $(f+K)(L) \neq fL + KL$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer to (1): There's no obvious reason why you can't do this, but you have to be *really, really* careful with this sort of stuff because it's very easy to get it wrong. What you're defining here is not a function, but an operation which acts on an expression (in a way that is not particularly clear, but the idea seems plausible).

Short answer to (2): Almost definitely not, in a direct sense. But this seems like a thing where someone with a deep knowledge of [universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra) could probably say a lot of intelligent things very quickly.

Short answer to (3): Not distributivity, definitely. Also possibly pretty much nothing else.

Long answer to (3): I will not attempt to more formally define these things, but I don't need to to answer (3). Abusing terminology, I will call the class of objects you've created 'operators', and I'll denote them by greek letters. (Of course, every function is an operator in a trivial sense, but if I write $f$ or $g$ I mean a function.)

The distributive property fails to hold: If, for instance, $g(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=2x$, and $\alpha$ is defined such that $\alpha p = -p$, and $\alpha+q=x^2-2x+5+q$ for any functions $p\not\equiv 1$ and $q$, then

$$(\alpha+f)g = (x^2-2x+5+2x)x^2 = x^4+5$$
$$\alpha f + fg = -2x+x^2$$

These two expressions are clearly not the same, and in fact they are not even equal at any real number. With more effort you could find examples that do not agree at any complex numbers either; of course these will not be polynomials.

[ I didn't work very hard to find this example; you can try it yourself and see there are lots of bad things that can happen.]

Distribuitivity is the only thing that I feel confident in saying that, probably no matter how you choose to define it, this will break.

But depending on how generally you allow operators to be defined, the associative properties may also fail to hold. In particular, the current version of the question allows for the failure of associativity. For instance if $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and $g(x)=e^x$, and $\alpha$ is defined such that $\alpha p=p$ for any $p\not\equiv 1$ and $\alpha q = -qx^5$ otherwise, then

$$\alpha(fg) = \alpha(1)=-x^5$$
$$(\alpha f)g = (f)g = 1 $$

of course these are not equal.

These are two examples of [ring axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), and we might ask whether other ring axioms fail. The previous example also shows that the existence of an identity fails. It is reasonable to suspect, in fact, that every single ring axiom fails; associativity and identity for addition fail if $0$ may be excluded in addition rules in a similar way that $1$ is excludable from multiplication rules. The last holdouts are the commutativity axioms; there is nothing from your example to suggest that these will fail.

Comment: I should mention that, despite the somewhat negative tone of the answer, I think the question is interesting. Perhaps it will be more convincing if I use words: the essential idea of [Schwartz's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_Schwartz) formalism for distribution theory (which finally placed the calculus of the Dirac delta function on solid ground) is the idea that functions should not be thought of input-output pairs but as "objects which can be integrated against"— in other words, not for what they do to their domains but what they do to other functions (in an extremely limited sense)

Comment: The idea of this question feels like another poke in that direction. Admittedly, it is less motivated and the evidence so far suggests the final objects would be much messier, but I think there is value in considering it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question. Essentially, you're asking whether or not "piecewise contextuous" entities can be formalized and reasoned about in a consistent way. The answer is yes, kind of. There's a monoid $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of all functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $F$ denote the monoid freely generated by $\{f\}$. Then we can form the coproduct $$C := \mathrm{End}(\mathbb{R}) \sqcup F$$ in the category of monoids.

Now let $f,g$ and $j$ denote arbitrary functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $\alpha : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote the floor function, let $\beta_x : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote multiplication by $x$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then since each of $f,g,\alpha$ and $\beta_x$ are elements of $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{R})$, hence they can also be viewed as elements of $C$. So let $\sim$ denote the least monoid congruence on $C$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. $\alpha f = g$
2. $\forall(x \in \mathbb{R})(x \neq 1 \rightarrow \beta_x f = g)$
3. $\forall \varphi \in \mathrm{End}(\mathbb{R})(\varphi \neq \alpha \wedge \forall x \in \mathbb{R}(x = 1 \vee \varphi \neq \beta_x) \rightarrow \varphi f = j)$

Then the quotient monoid $C /\sim$ is a place where the "piecewise contextuous" function $f$ you're trying to define actually exists and behaves as desired. But it's not really a function until you've specified an action of the monoid $C /\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}$, of course.

The first question you should ask yourself is whether the inclusion of $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{R})$ into $C /\sim$ is injective. If so, it might be possible to define an action of $C /\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}$ in such as to extend the usual action of $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}$.